# Oracle - How to Set Table and Index Statistics on empty table in order to test out explain plans?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-18c

I have an empty table with some indexes. I would like to test out different queries on this table to verify the explain plan is behaving as expected. Normally I would insert a large amount of fake data, ensuring that the indexed columns were selectable enough. This approach is a bit inconvenient however.

DBMS_STATS has some procedures that apparently allow you to set index and table statistics.

Is there a quick way to to set the statistics such that the query plan will tend to use a range scan on an index?

Comment: This seems a little confused, you want to fake statistics on your empty table to use an index in some queries to see if it will use the index? This seems more like you want to see if an index can legally be used, in which case hints and checking the execution plan is what you want to do. If you do want to go down the statistics path, do you not want them to represent some real data you’re trying to query?

Comment: Even if you would insert fake data it will not be useful. The Optimizer select indexes also based on it's data distribution. This might be completely different in fake data compared to some real data.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It is simple to insert fake data with sufficient selectivity to cause the optimizer to chose an index.

Comment: Yes, but do you know whether the real data will have similar cardinality? Why do you not simply insert real data? The optimizer does not only consider index statistics, it also considers the amount of data in your table (which is zero, so most likely it will never choose an index).

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Gathering and inserting real data of course is ideal, but for a quick test of a new feature/design I would prefer a method that doesn't involve expending a lot of time gathering and inserting real data, or even fake data. It would be convenient if there was a way to tell the optimizer "pretend there is 10 million rows in foo table, and column A is selective, but column B is not; what explain plan would you generate for this query?" This provides a quick sanity check on whether the tables, indexes, and queries in your design work under an ideal scenario.

Comment: It might be possible to copy statistics from another database and insert into your one. But certainly, that's even more effort you have to spend.